# I can't write to the path of the sd card

Tags: flutter, permissions

Exception has occurred.
PathAccessException (PathAccessException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/0F46-190D/screenshot.png' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13))

**Knowing that  I  added**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
    .....
</manifest>


<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    ....
</application>
```

Comment: On Android 11 12 13 it works, but the older one does not work on it

Comment: what's to output of the following command:  `adb shell ls -ld /storage/0F46-190D`?

Comment: adb shell ls -ld
I didn't understand this. Should I put it before the path?

Comment: run this command from the command line window

Comment: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: The problem is only in the storage on the SD card, it is always stored in the phone memory
In the SD card I can only store it inside the project path, but when I change the path to the main path of the SD card, this error appears, and as I said, this problem does not appear on all Android systems.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with Android 10 and Android 9

My problem was that I was using:

```
directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
if (!await directory.exists()) directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

This was working fine until some days ago but for some reason is failing now.
To solve it I change that code for this one:

```
directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
directory ??= await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

Tested on SM G390F Android 9, SM G965F Android 10, Redmi Note 8 Android 11, SM T505 Android 12 and works fine!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Dude! You saved my hours, thank you!! I thought my problem is with permissions but apparently not :)